# Tensorflow scalibility

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to train DNN, my network structure is very simple, each minibatch takes about 50ms when only one parameter server and one worker.  In order to process huge samples, I am using distributed ASGD training, however, I found that increasing worker count could not increase throughput, for example, 40 machines could achieve 1.5 million samples per second, after doubling parameter server machine count and worker machine count, cluster still could only process 1.5 million samples per second or even worse. The reason is each step takes much longer when cluster is large. Does tensorflow have good scalibility, and any advice for speeding up training?

Comment: My guess would be that I/O or the input pipeline more generally is the bottleneck. How are you reading data? Are your queues full?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I am not using any queue except file name queue. My graph reads raw data using tfrecord reader from SSD, and then parse the raw data using my custom operator. File IO and custom operator are not the bottleneck. Did anyone use very large cluster for training?

Comment: What is the no-training throughput of the input pipeline? And likewise, how many samples per second can you get on synthetic data? What is the utilization like for CPU/GPUs on each worker?

Comment: @AllenLavoie As I said my neural network is very simple, CPU is not the bottleneck, and only 20% utilization. The question is communication cost between worker and parameter server is too much if the cluster is large(I need to shard parameters to all parameter servers). I am not if you could share some numbers inside google or you are using different rpc implementation.

Comment: Interesting. What is the actual model?

Answer (score 2):

General approach to solving these problems is to find where bottlenecks are. You could be hitting a bottleneck in software or in your hardware.

General example of doing the math -- suppose you have 250M parameters, and each backward pass takes 1 second. This means each worker will be sending 1GB/sec of data and receiving 1GB/sec of data. If you have 40 machines, that'll be 80GB/sec of transfer between workers and parameter server. Suppose parameter server machines only have 1GB/sec fully duplex NIC cards. This means that if you have less than 40 parameter server shards, then your NIC card speed will be the bottleneck.

After ruling that out, you should consider interconnect speed. You may have N network cards in your cluster, but the cluster most likely can't handle all network cards sending data to all other network cards. Can your cluster handle 80GB/sec of data flowing between 80 machines? Google designs their own network hardware to handle their interconnect demands, so this is an important problem constraint.

Once you checked that your network hardware can handle the load, I would check software. IE, suppose you have a single worker, how does "time to send" scale with the number of parameter server shards? If the scaling is strongly sublinear, this suggests a bottleneck, perhaps some inefficient scheduling of threads or some-such.

As an example of finding and fixing a software bottleneck, see [grpc RecvTensor is slow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6116) issue. That issue involved gRPC layer become inefficient if you are trying to send more than 100MB messages. This issue was fixed in upstream gRPC release, but not integrated into TensorFlow release yet, so current work-around is to break messages into pieces 100MB or smaller.

The general approach to finding these is to write lots of benchmarks to validate your assumptions about the speed.

Here are some examples:

- [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/e196107b5e0afc834652bd3153030c42) sending messages between workers(local)
- [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ea1b1bae0a75c4aae593df7eca72d9ca) sharded PS benchmark (local)